# Xpath for ElementTree Reference to XML with Namespace for UK Statute Metadata

Tags: python, xml, namespaces

New to python but trying to access the metadata for a UK statute e.g. https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/12/part/3/chapter/4/data.xml - Chapter 4 of Part 3 of the UK Data Protection Act.

The problem is that there are two namespaces involved - uk legislation ukm: and the dublin core dc:

```
<Legislation xmlns="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/namespaces/legislation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DocumentURI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/12" IdURI="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/id/ukpga/2018/12" NumberOfProvisions="1103" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/namespaces/legislation http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schema/legislation.xsd" SchemaVersion="1.0" RestrictExtent="E+W+S+N.I." RestrictStartDate="2020-02-14">

<ukm:Metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ukm="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/namespaces/metadata">
<dc:identifier> 
...
```

How do I access the Legislation/ukm:Metadata element?

I've tried unsuccessfully using:-

```
statute_xml_tree = ET.parse(statute_xmi_doc)
statute_root = statute_xml_tree.getroot()
statute_metadata = statute_root.findall("{http://www.legislation.gov.uk/namespaces/metadata}Metadata")
```

along the lines of

> #All dublin-core "title" tags in the document

> `root.findall(".//{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}title")`

from https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be that a namespace prefix is required ;

```
dcmi_title = statute_root.find(mm_ns + "Metadata/" + dc_ns + "title").text
```

but the addition of namespaces produces lengthy XPath strings ...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach could be using lxml along with xpath() method:

```
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.parse('ukpga-2018-12-part-3-chapter-4.xml')
title = root.xpath(".//*[local-name()='Metadata']/*[local-name()='title']/text()")
```

Here notation `*[local-name()='Metadata']` means "every child having local name 'Metadata'", which gives ability to ignore namespaces.

Comment: Thanks - the wildcard approach looks interesting. The ability to get a parent element is helpful.